# ASAN: core file is not being generated when process gets aborted

Tags: rhel7, address-sanitizer

I've been trying to configure my service(running on RHEL 7), which involves my program compiled with libasan so that whenever my process aborts(due to invalid read or any other violation) a core dump gets generated. I've added the related ASAN flags in the environment variable in the service file:

Here's how my service unit file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description     = PROXY STARTUP FILE
After           = syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type            = simple
User            = testProxy
Group           = testProxy
Environment     = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/test/lib"
Environment     = "ASAN_OPTIONS=disable_coredump=false:unmap_shadow_on_exit=true:abort_on_error=true"
WorkingDirectory= /home/test
ExecStart       = /home/test/bin/proxy_2
ExecStop        = /bin/kill -9
ExecStartPre    = /home/test/service/pre_startup.sh
ExecStopPost    = /home/test/service/post_cleanup.sh
StandardOutput  = syslog
StandardError   = syslog
SyslogIdentifier = p2
LimitCORE       = infinity
Restart         = always
[Install]
WantedBy        = multi-user.target
```

[I've also followed the steps mentioned here relevant for RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/649193)

I've also set `ulimit -c unlimited`. I've added this in .bashrc file.

I'm adding some more info below(which might be relevant):

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/var/crash/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
```

But despite all this, core file wasn't generated when my process was aborted due to 'SEGV on unknown address'. Has anybody faced such issue before? What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

> But despite all this, core file wasn't generated

This is intentional: a core dump from sanitized process will take many terabytes on your disk, will take forever to write (if you have a large enough disk) and will be mostly useless.

I believe this is because address sanitizer runtime `mmaps` a lot of "shadow" memory which has very little use in the `core` dump, though I am hazy on details.

Comment: I should have mentioned that if my process is not running as a service then the core file does get generated. And no, it's size is not as huge as you think. The issue in my case is that due to some reason, the core file does not get generated iff the process is running as a service.